# virtualenv in python : can't create full files and activate not working

Tags: python, filesystems, virtualenv

I am creating a new python environment by using command `virtualenv myenv`. The command gets executed successfully. But whenever I try activating the environment I get nothing (no activation is taking place) when I open the created folder, the files available in virtual env are **libs, scripts and pyvenv.cfg** only. Nothing else other than these 3.

Comment: What is the OS you are working with?

Comment: I'm using windows, also using cmd in Windows

Comment: Does my answer working ? Else i sugger to reinstall virtualenv with pip.

Comment: No it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall virtualenv or with conda ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything. I still get the error

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your environment with venv:

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

And activate it normally.

In windows, you can use in the cmd :

```
py -m venv env
```

and activate it :

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```